# React call back on set state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> index.js:1 Warning: State updates from the useState() and useReducer()
> Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side
> effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with
> useEffect().

This is the error I get when trying to do this

```
setUnansweredQuestions({ newUnansweredQuestions }, () =>
                nextQuestion()
            );
```

I tried run a function after updating the state for unanswered questions but won't work cause it doesn't update right away.

I searched a bit and it is said to use useEffect but I already have one defined and won't let me create another. I just want to call the function nextQuestion after updating UnansweredQuestions

```
useEffect(() => {
        setUnansweredQuestions(questions);
        selectRandomQuestion();
    }, [currentQuestion]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with having multiple `useEffect`s.

Since you do `setUnansweredQuestions` and want to run something after that state variable changes, just do:

```
useEffect(nextQuestion, unansweredQuestions);
```

Comment: This will give me error, cause no data somewhere else, I assume will have to do some conditions if like this cause unanswered questions is empty at this point

Comment: What do you mean `cause no data somewhere else`?

Comment: nevermind it's fixed. Because unanswered questions is empty on page load and need to loop through it at some point later so need a check inside the effect but it works now

Answer (score -2):

You can try like this, I know this is not a good solution, but it works

```
  setState(UnansweredQuestions);
  setTimeOut(() => {
    nextQuestion()
  }, 16)
```